How to Move and Merge Targets Between Xcode Projects and Reuse Shared Files
I have several subprojects within a single Xcode project, and I need to merge two of them that are quite similar. These two subprojects share about 80% of their files, but there are also differences in the remaining 20% of the files. I want to consolidate these two subprojects into one and reuse the shared files efficiently.
Here’s what I need help with:

Copying Targets: Each project has several targets. What is the best way to move targets from one subproject to another within the same Xcode project, including transferring all build settings and configurations?

Reusing Shared Files: How can I effectively manage and reuse files that are common between the two subprojects, and handle the differences in the remaining files?

Adjusting Build Settings: What steps should I follow to ensure that the build settings from the source subproject are correctly applied to the merged subproject?


Also I am not sure what would be a good way to handle variables that differ per target. I have two files currently, that are literally the same, they just differ by some variable (some setting, that is defined per target.) So I want to use one file, instead of two and to set that variable appropriately per target. I have two ways in my mind. So, the first way would be to use "flags":
// SharedFile.swift
#if TARGET_ONE
let variableA = "123"
#elseif TARGET_TWO
let variableA = "345"
#endif

And the other way would be to use configuration files:
// SharedFile.swift
let variableA: String = {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Config", ofType: "plist"),
       let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path),
       let value = dict["variableA"] as? String {
        return value
    }
    return "default"
}()

I never done run into these requirements so I am not sure what is the way to go, and I would appreciate any advice about how handle this whole process. Thanks in advance for your help!

Alternative option - move the code into a swift package manager library then both projects can use that library?

As far as files it is the perfect example for Dependency Injection you can use protocols to have conforming classes for each targets, Settings should use Config files

@Meep That isn't an option sadly... Don't ask me why :) Not in my power.

To move and merge targets between Xcode projects and reuse shared files, first, open the source Xcode project and locate the target you wish to transfer. Use the "Show in Finder" option from the "File" menu to access the target folder, then copy and paste this folder into the destination Xcode project directory. In the destination project, add the copied files by selecting "Add Files to [Your Project]" from the "File" menu. To merge targets, open the destination project and adjust the target settings under the "Build Phases" tab to include any necessary files or frameworks from the old target, making sure to update build settings for compatibility. For reusing shared files, right-click in the "Project Navigator" of the destination project and select "Add Files to [Your Project]," then add the shared files and choose "Create folder references" if necessary. This method ensures efficient integration of targets and reuse of files between projects.
